# String to GML Object in Hibernate serialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, gml

I have GML string coming from Hibernate entity, I want to convert it to GML Object. Is there any thing like GML Object, like we have Geometry Object? What I am trying to do is to print to GML in the Browser so that its tags can be expanded, but now since I have the GML as a string, it just prints the GML as a string

```
"gml": [

"<gml:Polygon>\n <gml:outerBoundaryIs>\n <gml:LinearRing>\n <gml:coordinates>\n -83.675395,36.540759 -83.675395,39.466012 -75.16643499999999,39.466012 -75.16643499999999,36.540759 -83.675395,36.540759 \n </gml:coordinates>\n </gml:LinearRing>\n </gml:outerBoundaryIs>\n</gml:Polygon>\n"]
```

I want to print the GML so that the tags can be expanded.

Answer (score 0):

GeoTools can read GML v2 or 3 and give you a JTS geometry, which hibernate spatial uses:

```
import org.geotools.gml3.GMLConfiguration;
import org.geotools.xml.Parser;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;

Reader reader = new StringReader(gmlString);
GMLConfiguration gmlConfiguration = new GMLConfiguration();
Parser gmlParser = new Parser(gmlConfiguration);
Geometry geometry = (Geometry) gmlParser.parse(reader);
```

Here's [another example from the GeoTools tests](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/extension/xsd/xsd-gml3/src/test/java/org/geotools/gml3/GML3ParsingTest.java), but it uses a Feature instead of a Geometry.

Then use 
org.geotools.geojson.feature.FeatureJSON  or  [org.geotools.geojson.geom.GeometryJSON](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/geojson/geom/GeometryJSON.html) to take a Geometry instance and give a JSON string, like this:

```
GeometryJSON geometryJSON = new GeometryJSON();
String json = geometryJSON.toString(geometry)
```

I hope this is enough to get someone started.  Seems like there are not many code examples.